# Doctrine DQL subquery sum

Tags: sql, symfony2, doctrine2, php5

Как сделать сумму из двух count

SQL

```
SELECT (
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE location_id = :locationId) +
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE location_id = :locationId)
) count
```

DQL пробовал так

```
SELECT (
  (SELECT count(o) FROM MyBundle:Entity1 o WHERE o.location = :locationId) +
  (SELECT count(j) FROM MyBundle:Entity2 j WHERE j.location = :locationId)
) count
```

Но возникает ошибка

```
"message": "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 28: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'",
"class": "Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(item) FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON location_id = :locationId
WHERE location_id = :locationId
```

Или так, более точно сложно написать без конкретной базы

```
SELECT SUM(item) FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON location_id = :locationId
WHERE location_id = :locationId
```

Join в зависимости от того что нужно получить